# How to use get_template_part filter

Tags: wordpress

I am using a theme that has used `get_template_part()` to load certain areas of the theme. I want to override some areas with an alternate content. For example, my theme has this line in `header.php`.

```
get_template_part('parts/header/header.php');
```

I want to change `parts/header/header.php` with something else like `<p>New Content</p>`. I am trying to do this using a filter.

```
add_filter('get_template_part', 'xyz3021x');
function xyz3021x($part) {
    if($part === 'template-parts/header/header') return '<p>New Content</p>';
}
```

But this is not working. I am still getting the content of `parts/header/header.php`. How can this be done?

Comment: You must use `var_dump` to know exactly what the address of each part is. `add_filter('get_template_part', 'xyz3021x');
function xyz3021x($part) {var_dump($part);
    if($part === 'template-parts/header/header') return '<p>New Content</p>';
}`

Comment: The condition is working fine. Perhaps there is an issue with the way I have used this filter?